# Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I get the following error when I start my asp net mvc 4 application:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified
```

This is the error log

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = notebook\Guilherme
LOG: DisplayName = DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Guilherme/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Gedi/Gedi/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Gedi\Gedi\bin
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Gedi\Gedi\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/2635bb56/154c3fbb/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/2635bb56/154c3fbb/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Guilherme/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Gedi/Gedi/bin/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Guilherme/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Gedi/Gedi/bin/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/2635bb56/154c3fbb/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/2635bb56/154c3fbb/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Guilherme/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Gedi/Gedi/bin/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Guilherme/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Gedi/Gedi/bin/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.EXE.
```

I have already remove all references from DotNetOpenAuth with packager manager. Also I checked by my self references for every Auth assembly I had in my project and there is none.

This is my packages.config

```
<packages>
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.7.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.8.20.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.9.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="knockoutjs" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Repository" version="1.0.2.12" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RestSharp" version="103.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you don't want use OAuth, remove references: both the WebPages OAuth DLL (I think it's **Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll** <sup>1</sup>) and DotNetOpenAuth DLLs.

---

<sup>1</sup>: You can find the filename in `Calling assembly`. So, removing all `calling assembly` of `DotNetOpenAuth.Core` should work for you. This approach should work for other unused missing references.

Comment: It was helpful to see the reference name Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll since most references started with DotNetOpenAuth. That helped resolve the issue for me. Thank you Ian Li

Answer (score 78):

I had similar problem. It was really strange as the project was running OK a day before.

Removing obj and bin folders from the project folder, cleaning the solution and rebuilding it worked.

Comment: This probably worked by purging an oauth-related DLL that was already in your bin/obj folders. Removing the reference and rebuilding wouldn't remove the offending files, but blowing away the directories would.

Comment: Had the same issue, oauth dll was added, but no DotNetOauth dll was added. Cleaning didnt work, manually deleting bind and obj folders works. These small, but application-breaking-issues in visual studio  are starting to get on my nerves.

Comment: I have the same problem and deleting those folders doesn't work. I delete them, clean and rebuild the solution, and the issue remains

Comment: this oauth library uses webactivator to initialize so removing the references are not enough, the libraries have to be removed from the bin folder (webactivator enumerates dll files in the folder it was loaded in)

Comment: Just like chiapa I had same issue. I deleted bin and obj, cleaned and rebuiled, but issue remained. But then I **restarted visual studio and it worked**.

Answer (score 22):

I've seen this happen when deploying an MVC application as `bin deploy`. When you right-click on a project and select `Add deployable dependencies` VS will add the references to Oauth if you check the box next to `ASP .NET Webpages with Razor syntax`.

To fix this, delete the `_bin_deployableAssemblies` folder, and your application's `bin` folder and then clean and rebuild your application and it will work again.

Comment: I was trying to Run MSDN - Project Silk . the above steps helped me to solve the problem

Comment: instead of deleting the whole _bin_deployableAssemblies folder, just removing the Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth files from there was enough for me. (of course, clean and rebuild was also needed, as well as cleaning the target publishing folder)

Answer (score 16):

In my case the MVC4 application was running fine in the VS2012 debugger, but I was getting the "Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core'" error when I publish the application on the server.

Checking the "Delete all existing files prior to publish" checkbox on the settings tab of Publish Web window solved the issue.

[image: File System Publishing Settings]

Comment: This solved my problem although I was uploading to Azure and the tick box label was 'Remove additional files at destination'.

Comment: Delete all existing files prior to publish really worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I solved the problem by installing the package using Nuget

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth
```

Answer (score 4):

Just select "Remove additional files at destination" on publish settings.
This works for me

Comment: Such an easy solution should have 1k upvotes! I've been struggling with this for three days, trying to publish to Azure.

Answer (score 3):

By installing the following two packages I resolved this problem on VS2012 Professional Update 4 RC:

1. Open the Package Manager Console from the Menu:

   Tools| Library Package Manage | Package Manager Console
2. Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet
3. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers

Hope this helps for you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a global solution search (ctrl+shift+f if you haven't changed it) for the value '2780ccd10d57b246'. I'm guessing you'll find it in your web.config.

Comment: This is the problem... there is no reference. Find all "2780ccd10d57b246", Subfolders, Find Results 1, Entire Solution, ""
  Matching lines: 0    Matching files: 0    Total files searched: 182

Comment: What is the best way to complete remove DotNetOpenAuth* from my project? I have deleted the temp dir, excluded the bin and obj folders, re-built the solution and removed all OpenAuth and OpenID packages using packager manager console... I have no idea what to do now. Also googling by complete remove of DotNetOpenAuth There is no helpful result.

Answer (score 2):

One more solution option is to have assembly dependency as follows:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet"
                    publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246"
                    culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core"
                    publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246"
                    culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: please add content over here

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Please write out the relevant information from the link in your answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

for me, it worked like the following, using packager manager console, I've uninstall the packages, by the following order sequence and I re installed it, it solved my issue..

> Uninstalling

```
Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth
Uninstall-Package DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet 
Uninstall-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty
Uninstall-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core 
Uninstall-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer
Uninstall-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core
Uninstall-Package DotNetOpenAuth.core
```

Build, If you are not using the above packages then this should solve the problem, to Install the above again in case you need it, do the following..

> Reinstall

```
install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet 
install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth
install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty
install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core 
install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer
install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core
install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.core
```

recommanded:

- go to the bin folder of the project, clear it
- when to publish to the IIS, delete the virtual directory and assign the website again to the IIS, since I faced that issue of having cash in the server which was making the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the reputation to comment but I can verify that I had this exact problem and Jack gave the correct solution for me. I had recently pressed Add Service Reference and it broke the program with the above error message.

Deleting the _bin_deployableAssemblies folder, and your application's bin folder and then clean and rebuild your application made it work again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here. 
My published web.config didn't have the lines:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Just added and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I run into this issue when working on updating all of ours libraries. this link helped me fix this issue. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q554890/the-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-dotnetopenauth-core-version-4-0-0-0-error-message-is .

Specially I added these binding redirects to my web.config file.

```
      <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780CCD10D57B246" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780CCD10D57B246" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone - I was unable to uninstall the DotNetOpenAuth components through Nuget, so I resolved this error by deleting them from the references list directly and then re-installing dotnetopenauth through nuget.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error as well, but with an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I solved it by installing the Package DotNetOpenAuth.Mvc5 and calling AsActionResultMvc5() instead of AsActionResult()

Answer (score 0):

For me helped adding to csproj file the following section:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <PostSharpHostConfigurationFile>web.config</PostSharpHostConfigurationFile>            
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove BIN folder from wwwroot, and publish again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolved it on my end by removing Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth

Answer (score -3):

Remove any Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth dependencies everywhere in your projects.

Comment: and Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll from top response above