# General Advice for Resolving Dependencies (could not load file or assembly bla bla) in .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I'm new here to go easy.

I'm trying to publish my first asp.net 4.5 mvc 4 site to windows azure and I've got dependency issues. I can see that there are a plethora of existing posts and each one contains slightly different advice so I would appreciate general advice for troubleshooting these dependency issues. I'd be hugely grateful if you treated me like a layman in all regards.

For e.g.: my first publish error was:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is not referenced anywhere in my project in code, but has a reference to the assembely when I manually check (and the same version that the errors throws up, 4.0.0.0)

Now that I've tried to publish, I get an Oath error when I try to run locally that I did not get before:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

As per this post [Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942653/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-dotnetopenauth-core) I've since solved that particular issue which seemed to have arised post-publish by deleting the bin/obj folders, cleaning solution and changing some publish file settings.

Since then I get just another dependency issue:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

(Again in my references list with the "runtime version" as v4.0.30319 and "version as 2.0.0.0 in the properties tab, so I have no idea what to do with it)

So my final question is thus: what is the general process behind resolving these? I cannot google each one in sequence as they are slightly different each time and perhaps sometimes they may be referenced in packages.config and perhaps others not.

Is the process for example: check reference to assembly, if it exists then uninstall and re-install manually from nuget? Is there no automated way of doing this? And why can't I run locally anymore since I attempted to publish? I expected publishing to azure to be seamless and I'm a little disappointed.

Needing desperate help and thank you all,

Lani

EDIT1: to answer cory's question, here's a file explorer screenie and files showing up in VS with 'show all files' selected: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8qguuwicxz71ws/Screenshot%202014-10-19%2020.31.25.png?dl=0

I honestly don't know if that answers your question.

EDIT2: I've tried pointing the packages.config file to 4.0.0.0 for dotnetopenauth.core as per the error but the system cannot find any prior packages. I've also gone to http://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/5.0.0-alpha3 but it displays a list from 4.3.2 to 5.. I really think something is wrong in the project rather than for e.g. dotnetopenauth.core version... (or any other dependency issue that will inevitably arise after I resolve this one..)

Comment: Are the references being included in your output bin dir?

Answer (score 0):

These dependencies are done on the Web.Config file apparently on the `<assemblyBinding>` portion. You may also [reinstall](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages) Nuget package.