# Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

we are Getting error.

Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

i am stuck with issue and getting frustarte. please give your suggestion to resolve. Your kind support is valuable for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i have matched all dll related to DotNetOpenAuth.Core is in bin folder and inpackageid same

Comment: Check dll which you are using in your application and please check version from project properties. Simply error indicating for mismatch of version or dll dependency. [Could not load file or assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942653/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-dotnetopenauth-core)

Comment: _"The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference."_ means that manifest of some referenced assembly does not match that assembly reference. For example, in your project you reference `SomeRandomAssembly.dll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`, but in your bin folder you have `SomeRandomAssembly.dll, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089` (1.0.0.0 != 1.0.1.0) - outcome: your code go boom